# Nested assets not loading in Shopify dev

Tags: shopify, assets, shopify-template

I currently face the following problem:

I included a couple of assets (PNG images) in `src/assets/images/img.png`. Inside the snippet where I want to display the image, I wrote this (as defined in the documentation):

```
<img src="{{ '../assets/images/img.png' | asset_url }}"/>
```

When executing `slate build` I can also see those images show up during the build process in the log. But when I start my dev server (`npm run start:dev`) the link to the image is broken and it doesn't get displayed. Any thoughts on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your link is built all wrong. The Liquid filter asset_url resolves the path for you. All you need to provide is the name of the asset. So if you rewrite your Liquid correctly it would look like this:

```
{{ 'img.png' | asset_url }}
```

Reads as **hey Shopify, go find img.png in the assets and return for me the complete path to it**.